# Self checkout ou Self-checkout?

Tags: tradução-inglês, vocabulário, expressões-idiomáticas

Em um contexto português, como devo escrever autoatendimento em inglês: self checkout ou self-checkout, com ou sem hífen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu usaria com hífen: `self-checkout`.

Uma pesquisa rápida por "continente self checkout" confirma que esse é o uso mais comum, dando principalmente resultados com hífen:

- https://www.google.pt/search?q=continente+self+checkout

Comment: Encontrei em ambos os dicionários:

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/self-checkout

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/self-checkout

 a grafia escrita junta e com hífen: Self-checkout.